# How to add parameters to CFLint rule

Tags: json, configuration, code-analysis, cfml, cflint

I want to set specific parameters for the built-in [CFLint](https://github.com/cflint/CFLint) rules using CFLint 1.2.3. Unfortunately, there is currently no clear description how to do that.

So I tried to set them in different ways within the configuration having a look at the [project test files](https://github.com/cflint/CFLint/tree/master/src/test/resources/com/cflint/tests) and the [provided JSON schema](https://github.com/cflint/CFLint/blob/master/src/main/resources/schemas/.cflintrc.schema.json):

As defined in [one of the test files](https://github.com/cflint/CFLint/blob/master/src/test/resources/com/cflint/tests/VariableNameChecker/config/.cflintrc):

```json
{
  "rule" : [ 
    {
      "name": "VariableNameChecker",
      "className": "VariableNameChecker",
      "message": [
        {
          "code": "VAR_TOO_SHORT",
          "severity": "INFO",
          "messageText": "Variable ${variable} SHORTER THAN ${MinLength}!"
        }
      ],
      "parameter": [
        {
          "name": "MinLength",
          "value": "5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "inheritParent" : true
}
```

Within the rule object:

```json
{
    "rule": [ ],
    "excludes": [ ],
    "includes": [
        {
            "code": "VAR_TOO_SHORT",
            {
               "parameter": {
                   "MinLength": "5"
               }
            }
        }
    ],
    "inheritParent": false
}
```

As separate global property:

```json
{
    "rule": [ ],
    "excludes": [ ],
    "includes": [
        {
            "code": "VAR_TOO_SHORT",
        }
    ],
    "parameter": {
        "MinLength": "5"
    }
    "inheritParent": false
}
```

I also tried different naming conventions as parameter name like `VariableNameChecker.MinLength` and also writing `parameters` instead of `parameter`, though without luck.

What is the correct syntax to specify the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways to override a plugin param prior to CFLint 1.3.0 are 
(1) replace the cflint.definition.json file with your own
(2) set a system property in the form ClassName DOT parameter.  for example:
     java -DVariableNameChecker.MinLength=5 cflint-1.2.3-all.jar -file

In CFLint 1.3.0 the following will work:

```
{
    "parameters" : {
        "VariableNameChecker.MinLength": "5"
    }
}
```